# How do you hide ImageMagick?

Tags: imagemagick

I know that you can hide applications by going to `/usr/share/applications/`, selecting the `<appname>.desktop` and editing in `Hidden=true`. In this case however, I can't find imagemagick's `.desktop` file anywhere I search! I want to hide Imagemagick so badly because I won't use it but I can't uninstall it since so many other apps I'm using has Imagemagick as a dependency. So, any idea where this file is located?

Comment: Are you sure if you hide it the other programs that need it will still work?

Comment: Where do you want to hide it from? Where is it visible?

Comment: Have you looked in ~/.local/share/applications ? Don’t worry, other apps will work even if the .desktop file hides the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *.desktop file you are looking for is

```
/usr/share/applications/display-im6.q16.desktop
```